# How to create postman collection.json from the data in spreadsheet rather than using Postman GUI

Tags: javascript, automation, postman

Is it possible to create postman collection.json using the inputs(data) from spreadsheet? Rather than creating the collection using postman GUI.

Comment: The question is bit unclear to me, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to generate postman collection.json programmatically, instead of using the postman GUI and manually inputting the data for the request then export the collection